Is Elasticsearch suitable for address lookup from OCR-extracted data with fuzzy matching?
I am building a system where an OCR AI model extracts address information from documents. The extracted addresses can sometimes have errors, such as typos or formatting inconsistencies (e.g., misplaced spaces, missing parts). I plan to use Elasticsearch to search for the most relevant addresses from a pre-indexed database.
Here’s my proposed workflow:

Input: OCR extracts an address, e.g., "Seoul Gangnam Gu Nonhyeon Ro 123".
Indexing: Pre-defined addresses are indexed in Elasticsearch with fields like:


State
City
District
Road Name
Building Number
Tokens (a combined field of all relevant address components, tokenized for flexible search)


Search: Use Elasticsearch fuzzy queries or match queries with a fuzziness parameter to handle OCR-induced typos or formatting errors.
Result: The closest matching address is returned, with fields like zipcode, state, etc.

Here are the questions I’d like help with:

Is Elasticsearch an appropriate tool for this use case? Are there better alternatives for handling this type of fuzzy matching and search?
How can I ensure high recall and precision, given that OCR errors might introduce significant deviations (e.g., Nonhyeon might become Nonhyon)?
Should I use a single combined field (tokens) for searching, or would searching across multiple fields (state, city, road_name, etc.) with a bool query be more effective?
Are there any specific Elasticsearch settings or plugins (e.g., analyzers like nori for Korean or synonyms) that could improve the accuracy of this search system?
What limitations should I be aware of when relying on Elasticsearch for such approximate searches?
I’m open to architectural suggestions or insights from anyone who has tackled similar problems with OCR data and Elasticsearch. Thanks!


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
